# Get different results with the same query in T-SQL and LINQ (EF Core)

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to retrieve records from a database in Azure and for the checks I run T-SQL queries directly and then pass them to LINQ against the EF Core context, but I'm running into this problem.

[image: t-sql]

```
select FechaOrientativa,id, Archivo, Estado, Estudiar, Descripcion
from Concursos
where FechaOrientativa>=CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) and Estudiar='pt'
order by FechaOrientativa, Archivo, Estado
```

When I filter for the records with `FechaOrientativa` greater than or equal to Today, the `Estudiar` field is equal to 'pt', I get 2,296 records.

Now in Angular, I do http.Get to my Web API where I execute the following:

```cs
[HttpGet("sintratar")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Concurso>>> GetConcursosSinTratar()
{
    return await _context.Concursos.Where(c => c.Estudiar == "pt" && c.FechaOrientativa >= DateTime.Now).OrderBy(c => c.FechaOrientativa).ToListAsync();
}
```

And to my surprise, I receive only 2,151 records and I can't find an explanation.

Any idea, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems `DateTime.Now` and `GETDATE()` returns different result, that caused the difference. For testing, hard-code some static date time in both the places and execute it.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` include time, while `CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )` it returns date without time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare both SQL and EF LINQ queries, the difference is:

| From | Query/Code | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SQL | `CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )` | Returns current Date **without Time**. |
| EF LINQ | `DateTime.Now` | Returns current Date **with Time**. |

Hence the queried results are different.

(Example: Only queried records with the date-time field equal/after the query date-time).

From [Date and time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#date-and-time-functions), you are looking for `DateTime.Today`.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| DateTime.Today | CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) |

```cs
return await _context.Concursos
    .Where(c => c.Estudiar == "pt" && c.FechaOrientativa >= DateTime.Today)
    .OrderBy(c => c.FechaOrientativa)
    .ToListAsync();
```

---

Or you can use the SQL query in EF Core with [`.FromSqlRaw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#basic-raw-sql-queries).

```cs
return await _context.Concursos
    .FromSqlRaw(@"select FechaOrientativa,id, Archivo, Estado, Estudiar, Descripcion
        from Concursos
        where FechaOrientativa>=CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) and Estudiar='pt'
        order by FechaOrientativa, Archivo, Estado")
    .ToList();
```